# Is it safe to start a new thread in a BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I need to perform a network operation in a `BroadcastReceiver`.

So far I achieve it by starting a new thread:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // network stuff...
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Is there any risk that the process will be killed before the thread is done?

Is it better to use an `IntentService` instead? Any other better approach?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there any risk that the process will be killed before the thread is done?

If this receiver is registered via the manifest, yes.

If this receiver is registered via `registerReceiver()`, the lifetime of your process will be determined by other running components.

> Is it better to use an IntentService instead?

If that work will be over a few milliseconds, IMHO, yes, probably in concert with `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`.

> Any other better approach?

There is [a `goAsync()` option on `BroadcastReceiver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#goAsync()) that gives you a window of time to do work in another thread before triggering an ANR. I avoid this, because it is poorly documented. For example, it does not directly address your question: what is the process importance while this background thread is doing its work? Does this keep the device awake long enough for our work to get done? And so on. I'll use an `IntentService` or some other form of `Service`, where I have better understanding of the contract.

Comment: `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` is now deprecated

Comment: @douglas: Yes, if this question were to come up again, I would be recommending `JobIntentService`, or perhaps `WorkManager` (which still in beta right now).

Comment: @CommonsWare when I tested starting a background thread in a BroadcastReceiver without goAsync, it never ever got killed anywhere close the documented 10 seconds. It usually ran at least several minutes. I tested that on a real device and on emulators.
Why is that? Does that just mean my phone didn't need any resources so it didn't kill the process? 
Theoretically, a BroadcastReceiver can be killed immediately after onReceive returned?

Comment: @FlorianWalther: "Does that just mean my phone didn't need any resources so it didn't kill the process?" -- yes, or something else with greater importance was keeping your process alive (e.g., a foreground service). " Theoretically, a BroadcastReceiver can be killed immediately after onReceive returned? " -- yes (or, if you use `goAsync()`, you get the ANR timeout window to use).

Comment: Thank you! Actually, with goAsync the 10 seconds only apply if the sending intent use the flag FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND. If not, you have 30 seconds or more according to the documentation. On my tested emulators it was always pretty much exactly 1 minute.

Comment: Interestingly, when you call goAsync, the system is very strict when it comes to killing the process. But I am not sure if it actually kills the process, because the remaining receivers still get triggered (in an ordered broadcast) even if they are registered dynamically. If the process was actually killed, my dynamic receiver shouldn't be around anymore, should it?

Comment: @FlorianWalther: "If the process was actually killed, my dynamic receiver shouldn't be around anymore, should it?" -- correct, at least in normal cases. There may be some esoteric scenarios to consider. For example, if you have a manifest-registered receiver for the same broadcast, and you dynamically register an additional receiver for that broadcast in `Application#onCreate()`, does that dynamic receiver also receive the specific broadcast that triggered the manifest-registered receiver? Hopefully, you're not doing anything that funky. :-)

Comment: The dynamic receiver isn't registered in the manifest and it follows directly after the one that doesn't call PendingResult#finish and therefore gets aborted.
Could it be that once you call goAsync there is a different kind of mechanism aborting the broadcast which doesn't involve actually killing the process? I am sure the blocking broadcast never leaves his background thread but the next (dynamic) receiver still gets triggered after enough time passed.

Comment: Actually, sometimes the dynamic receiver triggers, sometimes not. It's very confusing :)

Comment: @FlorianWalther: "Could it be that once you call goAsync there is a different kind of mechanism aborting the broadcast which doesn't involve actually killing the process?" -- beats me. I haven't used `goAsync()`. For a long time, it was undocumented.

Comment: OK, I played around further and noticed that it only triggers the dynamic receiver the very first time. It seems that the process gets killed right after that, because when I navigate back to the app, it gets restarted.
So the process is actually killed if you call goAsync and don't obey the time window.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't the best idea. The life-cycle of a BroadcastReceiver lasts as long as it takes to finish calling onReceive(), after that it's destroyed. If you were to start running a new thread, there's a chance the BroadcastReceiver would be killed before the thread completes, which would wind up in some unexpected behaviour.

The better option would be to start a background service, like you said.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some practical information from my tests:

- The `onResume` lasts for **10 seconds**.
- The `Thread` itself lasts far longer. About **7 minutes** on an idle device.
- Filling about **450MB of RAM** (on a 4GB device) will stop the thread and garbage collect everything.
- Reliability is worse if the `BroadcastRecevier` is triggered while the device is in sleep-mode (by an `AlarmManager`). Most of the time it runs fine but sometimes it runs hours later when the phone get's unlocked and sometimes it doesn't run at all. (I used a `wake lock` too but I don't think it made much of a difference.)

This could be worth trying in some cases because from my experience the android specific threading solutions are not very reliable as well. Maybe for something like a widget button that fetches the latest weather forecast...